# Is it possible to force Azure IoT hub to save blobs as content type application/json

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

I have an IoT device which sends telemetry messages to an Azure IoT hub. The message does not have any attribute for content type. I am saving the received IoT telemetry messages in a blob, and found out that the hub is saving them with content type = application/octet-stream but I want them to be saved as content type = application/json. Since I am unable to modify the device and the message structure, is there a way to set up the IoT hub, the Route rule, or the blob storage itself, to force the content type to be application/json?

Screenshot of my hub custom storage endpoint, encoding setup to JSON.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grywc.png)

Comment: Does your device is connected to the Azure IoT Hub using a direct MQTT protocol? If yes, add the following properties on the *topic* in the device configuration:  **$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8**

Comment: @RomanKiss thanks for the hint; unfortunately, I do not have access to the device FW to edit it and add the suggested properties to the topic. Thus why I was wondering if I could do something on the hub or storage account, etc.

Comment: There is no way to change any message system properties such as a Content-Type, Content-Encoding, etc. in the Azure IoT Hub. I do recommend to use an Azure Function for your needs with triggering on the built-in endpoint with own consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

I did repro and found that might your IOT hub messages default set to blob as AVRO. please make use of the Encoding section to specify the message format such as JSON

The below picture show how we can navigate to IOT hub message routing and add a custom endpoint for storage and pick a container for storing the message of IOT hub.

[image]

[image]

> Note:  The data can be written to blob storage in either the Apache
> Avro format, which is the default, or JSON.
>
> The encoding format can be only set at the time the blob storage
> endpoint is configured. The format cannot be changed for an endpoint
> that has already been set up. When using JSON encoding, you must set
> the contentType to JSON and the contentEncoding to UTF-8 in the
> message system properties.

Reference: Tutorial - [Configure message routing for Azure IoT Hub using Azure CLI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing)

Please go through the route to storage account section in the above document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did set the encoding property of storage account to JSON (exactly as you showed in the screenshot) but the saved blobs property Content Type is always saved as application/octet-stream which is the default of the hub when the content type is not set in the topic itself. I was wondering if there is some other setting that could be used to force the hub/the storage account to save the blobs in JSON.

Comment: please see my attached screenshot. The storage endpoint encoding is set to JSON.